# Get value from dialog window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble getting the value of a textbox of a popped up dialog. I've followed the advice from other StackOverflow questions that said to create a public variable in program.cs:

```
public static string cashTendered { get; set; }
```

Then I created my dialog like this:

```
Cash cashform = new Cash();
cashform.ShowDialog();
```

And when the user presses the button on the dialog, this is called:

```
        if (isNumeric(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float))
        {
            Program.cashTendered = textBox1.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount of cash tendered. E.g. '5.50'");
        }
```

Yet Program.cashTendered stays null. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters your form called `Cash` should use an object oriented design.  It should have a public property called `CashEntered` or something similar of type `decimal` instead of string.  You would call the Form like so:

```
using (var cashDialog = new CashDialog())
{
    // pass a reference to the Form or a control in the Form which "owns" this dialog for proper modal display.
    if (cashDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ProcessTender(cashDialog.CashEntered);
    }
    else
    {
        // user cancelled the process, you probably don't need to do anything here
    }
}
```

Using a static variable to hold the results of a temporary dialog is a bad practice.  Here is the better implementation of a dialog:

```
public class CashDialog : Form
{
    public decimal CashEntered { get; private set; }

    private void ok_btn_Clicked
    {
        decimal value;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(cashEntered_txt.Text, out value))
        {
            // add business logic here if you want to validate that the number is nonzero, positive, rounded to the nearest penny, etc.

            CashEntered = value;
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount of cash tendered. E.g. '5.50'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nathan You're welcome.  This way you can reuse the dialog anytime you want cash entered, or even share it with other projects.

Comment: what about if you are going to hold an object of the Dialog, wouldn't the calling form end up with a bunch of properties of several types, is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

On your main form that you want to get the value for, you'd have some sort of code like this;

```
        var cashTendered;
        using (var frm = new Cash())
        {
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                cashTendered = frm.GetText()
        }
```

Then on your dialog form, you'd have something like this:

```
        public string GetText()
        {
                return textBox1.Text;
        }

        public void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
        }

        public void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.Close();
        }
```

Alternatively, you can just perform those lines in the btnClose_Click event in the FormClosing event instead if you don't have a button for them to click to 'submit' their value.

**Edit** You might want to add some sort of validation on your textbox inside the btnClose event, such as:

```
 decimal myDecimal;
 if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out myDecimal))
 {
      this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
      this.Close();
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry", "Error");
     textBox1.SelectAll();
 }
```